# Porting a chrome extension to firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

First of all: This is no duplicate of "how to automaticly convert a chrome extension"...

I wrote a complex chrome extension which is quite popular. So a lot of people asked me to publish a firefox - version.

I am currently in a quite early state of analyzing the difficulties I might run into. I am able to map most chrome-specific commands to others in firefox.

Just one topic is unsolved until now:
Chrome uses content-scripts and background-scripts.

the communication works that way:
Content-Script:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
{
   Action: "LoadAll"
}, function(response)
{
   mySetting= response.Setting;
}
);
```

background-script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
   function(request, sender, sendResponse)
   {
      if (request.Action === "LoadAll")
            {
               sendResponse({Setting: "hello out there!"});
               return true;
            }
      )
    });
```

(please ignore if I might have missed a bracket)

How is this communication been done on firefox extensions? Or does FF recommend a complete different approach?

If there is no "Take this command" - answer, a link to a more in-depth-explanation would be nice.

Comment: I assume you want to do a Fiefox SDK-addon? Please fix tag.

Comment: @Blargh It doesn't seem so.

Comment: What exactly is that doing? Like is there a button in the HTML DOM and you want it onclick to fire a function that is inside your addon? If that's the case let me know i have a few solutions for you.

Comment: @Noitidart it is much more. The Extension has an options menu where I can enter some properties. These setting are then needed in a "normal" website I manupulate (just one example of the actions taken place)

Comment: "Inline options" are a piece of cake with firefox. So to sum up your addon, it's some options and then on page load of a certain host? certain href? you inject/maniuplate it?

Comment: @Noitidart Not only on page load, but also on DOM-Change, but yes: That is the way the addon works. To be specific. Thats the extension: http://goo.gl/iu0GhD

Comment: What do you mean DOM-Change? I can set you up for this easily. Does DOM-change mean PJAX?

Comment: I mean "document.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified")... but this is getting OT, I think

Comment: Ooo yikes thats a dangerous event, consider [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), also do you want your addon options inline in the addon manager or are you going to inlay into the website?

Comment: I modify the website (google+) itself removing dom elements and adding others

Comment: **DO NOT!!!** use DOMSubstreeModified event. It's ultra easy to use MutationObserver it's place. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Performance_best_practices_in_extensions#Avoid_DOM_mutation_event_listeners

Answer (score 2):

The thing you are looking for is [Message Manager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_message_manager). We are developing a big and complicated extension for about 2 years for Fx and recently made a good Chrome port of it. Messaging process differs strongly in Fx and Chrome. Think of it like you inject a content script in window/browser/tab, which has few things in common with content scripts in Chrome, and then talk to your extension code from injected script via sendSyncMessage/sendAsyncMessage. I hope this helps.